# View being called twice/object created twice

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-views

I have a `Comment` model with 2 views: 1 for parent comment and one for replies. The parent view works fine but for some reason my reply view gets called twice, which creates 2 reply objects at once. So first off here's a `.reply` button the user clicks which brings up the comment form and giving that comment form an `onclick` value of `reply_comment()`:

```
$('.reply').on('click', function(e) {
    var clone = $('.comment_form').clone();
    parent_id = $(this).closest('.comment_div').data('comment_id');
    $(this).closest('.comment_div').after(
        clone
    );
    clone.addClass('reply_comment_form').removeClass('comment_form');
    clone.attr('onclick', 'reply_comment()');
    clone.data('comment_id', parent_id);



    $(this).next().css('display', 'inline-block');
    $(this).css('display', 'none');
    $('.reply_comment_form').css('padding', '1px');

});
```

And here's the actual function:

```
function reply_comment() {
    $('.reply_comment_form').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        parent_id = $('.reply_comment_form').data('comment_id');

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/comment_reply/',
            data: {
                reply_text: $(this).find('.comment_text').val(),
                parent_id: parent_id,
                id: path,
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: $("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']").val(),
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $('.reply_comment_form').replaceWith("<div class='comment_div new_comment'><div class='left_comment_div'>" +
                "<div class='username_and_votes'><h3><a href='#' class='username'>" + data.username +
                "</a></h3><span class='upvotes' style='margin: 0 6'>0</span><span class='downvotes'>0</span></div><br><p>" + data.reply_text +
                "</p></div><a href='#'><span class='comment_delete'>x</span></a></div>");
                $('.new_comment').css({
                    'width': '72%',
                    'margin': '0 70 10 0',
                    'float': 'right',
                });
                 $('.new_comment').next().css('clear', 'both');
                 $('.new_comment').prev().find('.cancel_comment').css('display', 'inline-block')
                     .find('.cancel_comment').css('display', 'inline-block');
            }

        });


    });
}
```

this AJAX call successfully appends the reply, and is sent to this view to save it to the database:

```
def comment_reply(request):
    print('reply')
    if request.is_ajax():
        comment = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
        reply_text = request.POST.get('reply_text')
        id = request.POST.get('id')
        parent_id = request.POST.get('parent_id')
        parent = Comment.objects.get(id=parent_id)

        if comment.is_valid():
            comment = Comment.objects.create(comment_text=reply_text, destination=id, user=request.user, parent_id=parent_id, parent_comment=parent)
            username = str(request.user)
            return JsonResponse({'reply_text': reply_text, 'username': username})
```

Everything works fine, except this view gets called twice and creates 2 `Comment` objects. Any idea why it does this?

Comment: The code looks unnecessarily complicated. I think you dont need to wrap the `onsubmit` into the `reply_comment()` function at all. I think the `onclick` you have there could be performed multiple times, and then the `onsubmit` thing is bound twice too.

Comment: I tried `$('.reply_comment_form').on('submit', function {` by itself but it wasn't called. Doing the onsubmit think is the only option I have.

Comment: of course, because the element does not exist at the time when the document is created. Try something like this instead: `$(document).on('submit', '.reply_comment_form', function(e) { ...`

Comment: That worked thankyou so much. What exactly is  your code doing differently to `$('.reply_comment_form').on('submit', function {` ?

Answer (score 0):

Summing the comments into an answer:

Not sure why exactly it's bounded twice, but I believe the `onclick` even could be triggered multiple times, which leads to a multiple binding of `onsubmit`

difference between these two pieces:

```
$('.reply_comment_form').on('submit', function(e) {
```

and

```
$(document).on('submit', '.reply_comment_form', function(e) {
```

The code is executed `ondomready` (ie. when the DOM document is ready), and at that time `.reply_comment_form` does not exist yet, so the `submit` event is not hooked to anything.

The second piece is executed in a scope of `$(document)` which exists, and the second parameter in `on()` says which elements it should be limited to. Its performance is a bit worse (since it has to watch the whole document), but it works.